# worklight j_security_check not found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, j-security-check

I'm using Worklight Studio Plugin 6.0.

I am trying to get FormBasedAuthentication working. When I run and deploy my worklight project, the app login page is presented successfully. However when I click on the login button, an error is thrown on the server console:

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/j_security_check [project DojoTest]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/j_security_check

This directory doesn't exist in the project. I've tried creating another project but it doesn't add the missing folder.

Any advise is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<div id=BorderDiv>
                <div class=imageDiv id="imageDiv">
                    <center style="color:#66FF66">
                        Test
                    </center>
                </div>
                    <fieldset id="loginFieldSet">
                        <legend>Login:</legend>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/FormLayout"
                            data-dojo-props="columns:'auto'">
                            <div>
                                <label>User name*: </label> <input id="username" type=text
                                    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" size="50"
                                    placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required></input>
                            </div>
                        <div>
                                <label>Password*: </label> <input id="password" type=password
                                    name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" size="50"
                                    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" required> </input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <center>
                                <input type="button" class="formButton" id="AuthSubmitButton" value="Login" /> <input type="button" class="formButton" id="AuthCancelButton" value="Cancel" />
                            </center>
                        </div>

                    <!--  <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" onclick="login()">Login</button>-->
                    </fieldset>
            </div>

//Create the challenge object
var challengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("SampleAppRealm");

    /*
     * Read the response of the challenge. The default login form
     * that the server returns contains a j_security_check string.
     * If the challenge handler detects it in the response, return true
     * 
     */
    challengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
            return false;
        }
        var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');

        if (indicatorIdx >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    //Hanlde the Challenege. In our case, we do nothing!
    challengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
    //do nothing
    };

    //Bind the login button to collect the username and the password
    $('#AuthSubmitButton').bind('click', function () {
        var reqURL = 'j_security_check';
        var options = {};
        options.parameters = {
            j_username : $('#username').val(),
            j_password : $('#password').val()
        };
        options.headers = {};
        challengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, challengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
    });

    $('#AuthCancelButton').bind('click', function () {
        alert("Cancel Clicked");
        sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
    });

    challengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback = function(response) {
        var isLoginFormResponse = challengeHandler.isCustomResponse(response);
        if (isLoginFormResponse){
            challengeHandler.handleChallenge(response);
        } else {
            login();
            $('#password').val('');
            $('#username').val('');
            challengeHandler.submitSuccess();
        }
    };

    function login(){
        require([ "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry" ], function(dom, registry) {
            var username = dom.byId("username");
            var password = dom.byId("password");
            alert("username= " + username.value + " AND password = "
                    + password.value);

            try {
                registry.byId("mainMenuView").performTransition("myAcctView", 1,
                        "slide");
                WL.Logger.debug("Moved to My Account view");
            } catch (e) {
                WL.Logger.debug("Error Caught: " + e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not a directory in your project. It's an address the app is attempting to access. Your implementation is incorrect. Please take a look at the form-based authentication sample, and also read its accompanying tutorial. If it's still not working for you then you really need to supply your project (this is a programming Q&A website - please provide Code). See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html?cp=SSNJXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form-based authentication it is expected from the server to send a login form in response to a connect attempt (you are not required to display the HTML sent by the server, it's just the response that matters mostly).

Basically, if your app's first screen is the login form and you click some login button and this button does a login attempt, it will first the first time, because only in the first time will the server get a request from the app and the response to that request would be the challenge - the login form.

So you need to make sure that you first connect to the server using WL.Client.connect and only then allow the user to do any login attempts (can be a login button). This is the usual scenario why the above error is given.

Note also that this is not a resource that exists in your Worklight project; it's a resource that exists on the server. This is why you cannot find it.

Please review the authentication concepts and form-based tutorial (and its sample)  user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html?cp=SSNJXP

Comment: I have pasted the code as requested. The message I recieved from your answer is that a connection to the server needs to be established first. Can you please highlight where this needs to be made.

Comment: I have pasted the code as requested. The message I received from your answer is that a connection to the server needs to be established first. At which point do I connect to the server? In the challenge handler before creating the challenge object?

Also removing of the the back slash  var reqURL = /'j_security_check'; from the request URL has fixed the error (j_security_check mising) but I now have to click the login button twice to log into the application. This ties into your answer as the login in form is presented as a challenge.

Comment: In wlCommonInit(), the first thing the app logic does.

Comment: I add in wlCommonInit but the challenge only appears when I call one adapter. Can I call challenge when start the app without call adapter?

Comment: You put the security test on the application environment in application-descriptor.xml

Comment: Yes, I use the LDAP example and work perfect, but first need to call adapter to get a challenge. It's possible have the challenge without call adapter?

Comment: You did say tihs tag in application-descriptor.xml: <userIdentityRealms>ScotiaRealm</userIdentityRealms>?

Comment: No. The one that starts with your ENVIRONMENT name, i.e <android ...> or alike.

Comment: <iphone bundleId="com.tl" version="1.0">
  <worklightSettings include="false" />
  <security>
   <encryptWebResources enabled="false" />
   <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false"
    ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3" /></security></iphone>

Comment: yes... you need to add securityTest="......" after bundleId. Why not just read the documentation?