# Facing issues while integrating Mobilefirst CLI 7.1 with ldap

Tags: authentication, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

I am using mobile first CLI 7.1 and trying to integrate with the LDAP.

I am following [this](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/using-ldap-login-module-to-authenticate-users-with-ldap-server-in-hybrid-applications/) document to implement. I am getting 401 error (`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`) when loading the application for first time in the browser. I am getting 500 error(`POST http://localhost:10080/Project/apps/services/j_security_check 500 (Internal Server Error)`) when I try to logging in. I have uncommented wl.client.connect and gone through the following conversations at stackoverflow. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188857/worklight-j-security-check-not-found), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810504/j-security-check-not-found-worklight) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868734/sesn0008e-a-user-authenticated-as-anonymous-has-attempted-to-access-a-session-o)

**Server Logs**

```
 [ERROR   ] SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:BasicRegistry/admin.
 [ERROR   ] SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:BasicRegistry/admin.
 [ERROR   ] SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:BasicRegistry/admin.
 [ERROR   ] SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:BasicRegistry/admin.
```

**What is my scenario?**

User is initially taken to login page and later when he clicks on login I will collect the details and automatically set to j_secutity_form when it throws challenge and submit. I am getting 401 when I open the application and getting 500 when I click on login. which calls

```
var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
        var options = {};
        options.parameters = {
            j_username : loginData.email,
            j_password : loginData.password
        };
        options.headers = {};
        ldapRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options,ldapRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
```

**I have following questions:**

1) Is the documentation that I am following is complete or it needs some additions thing that need to be done ?

2) What is the cause for getting blocked with the above errors

**And here is my code:**

```
var ldapRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("LDAPRealm");

ldapRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }
    var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');

    if (indicatorIdx >= 0){
        return true;
    }  
    return false;
};


ldapRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
};

ldapRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback = function(response) {
    var isLoginFormResponse = ldapRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse(response);
    if (isLoginFormResponse){
        ldapRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(response);
    } 
    else {
        ldapRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
    }
};  

logout = function(){
    WL.Client.logout('LDAPRealm',{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to session independence mode which is turned ON by default as of MFP 7.1. I think this might explain why you are getting the SESN0008E error. [Here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html) is a link to an article that explains how to disable session independence.

There is more information on the SESN0008E error [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187598/how-can-we-disable-the-exception-sesn0008e-a-user.html).

Please let me know how you get on.